# Querying the Database | Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Here's my models,

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField()

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer_text = models.TextField(max_length=15000)
```

I'm trying to print those Questions which received an answer most recently. Here's what tried,

```
questions = Question.objects.filter(answer__isnull=False).order_by('-answer__id').distinct()
```

But the problem is that even after adding distinct in the end it's still returning the same question multiple times. I also tried by doing, `distinct('answer__id', 'id')` but nothing worked.

How can we do that with the Question model? Thank You . . .

Comment: Try this:
questions = Question.objects.filter(answer__set__isnull=False).order_by('-answer__id').distinct()

Comment: @Farrukh Sir, it's raising an error, `Related Field got invalid lookup: set`. On removing set it's not working the way it should